# How to show that $ALL_{DFA}$ is in P

Tags: computer-science, automata

How can I show that $ALL_{DFA}$ is in P ?

$ALL_{DFA}  = \{ \langle A \rangle \mid A \text{ is a DFA and } L(A) = \Sigma^* \}$

Comment: What is $ALL$? (presumably $DFA$ is determinsitic finite automaton). And then what is their relation in $ALL_{DFA}$?

Comment: @Mitch: Edited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that a DFA accepts $\Sigma^*$ if and only if all reachable states from the start state, $q_0$, are accepting. This can easily be decided in polynomial-time by performing a breadth- or depth-first search on the DFA from $q_0$.  If at any time a non-accepting state is visited, *reject*, otherwise, if only accepting states are found, *accept*.

Interestingly, this problem is much harder for NFAs; $\{ \langle A \rangle \mid A \text{ is an NFA and } L(A) = \Sigma^* \}$ is NP-hard.

Comment: I have understood edit part. Apart from that I could not see how using $\overline{ALL_{DFA}}$ additionally helps.

Comment: It is just another school of thought.  But you are correct; I didn't use it in my solution.

Comment: Why is your last claim so, given that an NFA can be converted into a DFA?

Comment: @actinidia DFAs can be exponentially larger than their NFA counterparts, so converting to a DFA does not give a polynomial-time algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

We create a TM F that decides the problem in polynomial time on input $D$, a DFA, with final states $F$ and states $D$.

F: On input $<D>$

1. Accept if $F = Q$
2. Check if there is at least one state in $Q - F$ that is reachable using BFS.
3. If there is no such state, accept, otherwise reject.

So F decides $ALL_{DFA}$ since it accepts iff $D$ accepts $\Sigma^*$, and it is polynomial since we use BFS, it takes at most $O(n)$.

Since D is a DFA, and if every reachable state in D accepts, so D must accept all possible strings. If a non-accepting reachable state exists, then there must be some string that D doesn't accept.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My answer to this problem on a recent homework was originally similar to the other answer on this question: Perform a breadth first search on the input, If a non-accept state is visited reject, Otherwise accept.  However, this solution is **wrong**. This decider will accept a DFA that does not accept all inputs if, for example, there is no transition for one of the characters in Σ. The following DFA (with an alphabet of 0 and 1) is an example of this. It will not accept inputs with a 1, but there is no reject state that will cause this DFA to be rejected by the decider.

[image: The decider accepts this DFA but this DFA does not accept all inputs.]

The answer is actually to construct the *complement* to the input and test whether the language of the complement is an empty set.  You can do this by doing a breadth or depth first search on the complement and if an accept state is found, reject the input and otherwise, accept.

Comment: Factually what you are saying is wrong : a DFA must have a complete transition function by complete i mean that for any state you have a transition for any element of the alphabet to an other states. This come from the Definition of a DFA if it's not the case then you work on a NFA.